# Software-rec tag; disclaimer looks cut off

Tags: bug

I stumbled across a [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1336453/windows-app-that-incubates-other-windows-apps) that is on hold, so I checked out the reason why, and eventually found the [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) tag, which I thought was weird since SuperUser didn't do software rec's and there's [a-whole-nother SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) for that.

Looking at the tag, there's a disclaimer/notification at the top, and it appears that the URL is cut off (it's not), and the URL is not clickable.

I think the text should be modified so that it's clear the URL is complete, and the URL should be clickable.

[image]

Comment: You should propose an improvement to the tag information.  Any improvements made to it will be approved by the community.  I already proposed a change.  Formatting does work in tag usage guidance.  So I simply remove the links and cleaned up the grammar.

Comment: Tap the "Learn more" link under the tag information and you'll see the full excerpt.

Comment: @Mokubai that's how I knew the URL was complete.